# Deduplicating Files while moving them to XFS

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs, deduplication

I've got a folder on a non `reflink`-capable file system (ext4) which I know contains many files with identical blocks in them.

I'd like to move/copy  that directory to an XFS file system whilst simultaneously deduplicating them. (I.e. if a block of a copied file is already present in a different file, I'd like to not actually copy it, but to make a second block ref point to that in the new file.)

One option would of course be first copying over all files to the XFS filesystem, running `duperemove` on them there, and thus removing the duplicates after the fact. Small problem: this might get time-intense, as the target filesystem isn't as quick on random accesses.

Therefore, I'd prefer if the process that copies over the files already takes care of telling the kernel that, hey, that block is a duplicate of that other block that's already there.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: can duperemove be used to find duplicated extents before copying the files?

Comment: not that I'd be aware of, but good idea. I'd still have to do the deduplication *after* moving, however.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is not an answer to the question, but instead an answer to a question that was not asked (how to detect and de-allocate duplicate files)

my approach is to make a directory that has a hadlink that is a hash of every file.

if the hash already exists I replace the file with a hard-link from the hash, if the hash file does not exist, I create a new hard link from the file in the hash directory.

something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dupes=/mnt/xfs/.dupes_dir
for x in "$@"
do
    sha=$( sha1sum "$x" | cut -d\  -f1 ) 
    if [ -e $dupes/$sha ] 
    then
        ln -f $dupes/$sha "$x" 
    else
        ln "$x" $dupes/$sha
    fi
done
```

Comment: But I don't want hardlinks, but reflink COW block reuse. The idea is still appreciated.

Comment: sorry, I didn't read the question propperly.  will delete this.

Comment: don't know, it's still a valid approach, if we find a way to do intra-file block deduplication this way. (also if we can keep all the file attributes intact in the process)

Comment: If `$dupes/$sha` doesn't exist yet, copy the file `$x` from ext4 to `$dupes/$sha` on xfs. After `fi`, `cp --reflink=always $dupes/$sha /mnt/xfs/target/"$x"` (and before `if` create the target folder with `mkdir -p $(dirname /mnt/xfs/target/"$x"`). I haven't tested this. If it works please edit the answer so people do not have to read the comments. May want to add `touch --reference`, `chmod` etc. to set time stamps and other metadata correctly.

Comment: Though not available by default, [xxHash](https://cyan4973.github.io/xxHash/) is most likely a faster alternative to SHA1.

Answer (score 0):

*I moved my comment to an answer so I have more room.*

I don't know if there is a way to do it on copy. I wish there was because I sync a lot of drives and I make a lot of reflink file copies. Btrfs supports a "send" mechanism that I think does deduplication. I use XFS for most things though.

The deduplication utilities I have looked at are slow. Not just slow, **incredibly slow**. Nearly impossible to use at least on mechanical drives. The reason is because the operation is fully synchronous so it absolutely hammers the disk.

I have been meaning to write a utility (possibly needing a patched kernel) that uses cache instead. It will be less safe but way, way faster, making it actually usable. I was kind of waiting for someone to do this and would like to hear about any such utility if it exists.

Another option that I haven't tried yet is to connect the drive to a virtual machine and run the deduplication in there. Then you can enable forced "unsafe" caching on the backend. This will be unsafe of course but hopefully a whole lot faster.